# Laravel 5.4 Query Builder SUM() from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm having problems getting the SUM of a certain field from two tables.

So to start things off, here's my query.

```
        //Getting of Cost of Goods Sold (Menus)
        $totalMenuCost = DB::raw('(SUM(orders.qty * orders.cost)) as cost');
        $yearMenuSold = DB::raw('YEAR(orders.created_at) as year');

        $menuscost =  DB::table('orders')
            ->where('status', 'served')
            ->select($totalMenuCost, $yearMenuSold);

        //Getting of Cost of Goods Sold (Items)
        $totalItemCost = DB::raw('(SUM(purchases.qty * purchases.cost)) as cost');
        $yearItemSold = DB::raw('YEAR(purchases.created_at) as year');

        $itemcost =  DB::table('purchases')
            ->where('status', 'served')
            ->union($menuscost)
            ->select($totalItemCost, $yearItemSold)
            ->get();
```

And when I try to do `return $itemcost`. It returns two rows:

```
[
  {
    cost: "792.00",
    year: 2017
  },

  {
    cost: "1700.00",
    year: 2017
  }
]
```

I'm trying to make it return a single row but having it added, like this:

```
[
  {
    cost: "2492.00", // that's 1,700 + 792
    year: 2017
  }
]
```

Comment: Your union should be just before `->get()`, try using group by as well

Comment: @SagarGautam I switched `select` and `union`. So `union` will be just before `->get()` and added `->groupBy('cost')` just before `union`. But it has the same output.

Comment: Yes, use `->groupBy()` according to your requirement , Here you can group by year to get your output

Comment: @SagarGautam I tried using `->groupBy('year')` too. Still shows the same output, hehe.

Comment: in $itemCost you can again do the Sum of cost column and group by year.

Comment: @Rohitshah that's what I did, or maybe that's another syntax that I'm imagining differently? Can you provide an example please?

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Can you please try what I've added. Take a moment to view it

Answer (score 0):

```
$itemcost =  DB::table('purchases')
            ->where('status', 'served')
            ->union($menuscost)
            ->select($totalItemCost, $yearItemSold)
            ->get();
```

In your Example you are just selecting $totalItemCost, $yearItemSold and union from other table ($menuscost).

So that won't add up the results.

///////////Try Changing your Query in this Format

```
select column1,sum(column2) total
from
(
    select column1,column2
    from Table1
    union all
    select column1,column2
    from Table2
) t
group by column1
```

Hope this Helps..
Let me know if more help is needed.

Comment: That's what I thought too, hmm. So I can add them with the `select()` method?

Comment: @jan-ariel-san-jose have you solve your issue?
I got similar problem, can I know how your fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

All seems okay, Have you changed your `$itemcost` like this

```
$itemcost =  DB::table('purchases')
             ->where('status', 'served')
             ->select($totalItemCost, $yearItemSold)
             ->union($menuscost)
             ->groupBy('year')
             ->get();
```

**UPDATE**

Since above not working for your case,

I think problem on group by is with union so Have a new try with this one.

```
$menuscost =  DB::table('orders')
        ->where('status', 'served')
        ->select($totalMenuCost, $yearMenuSold)
        ->groupBy('year');

$itemcost =  DB::table('purchases')
             ->where('status', 'served')
             ->select($totalItemCost, $yearItemSold)
             ->groupBy('year')
             ->union($menuscost)
             ->groupBy('year')
             ->get();
```

If this is not working then can you add output of this query.

Comment: I tried this one as what you said earlier... but the output is still the same, no changes whatsoever. xD

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Same output ?

Comment: It still returns two set of data. Both when groupBy is above or below the `union()` method

Comment: Still the same output with 2 sets of data. xD. I'm starting to think something's wrong with my `DB::raw` query.

Comment: @JanArielSanJose ha ha seems some serious problem though :D :D

Comment: Yea, haha. Thanks for sticking up tho! :)

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Ha ha